# Magento 2 Admin Grid Columns Not Displaying

Tags: magento2, grid, admin-panel

[image]

I installed magento2 latest version in ubantu and apache server admin grid view columns not displaying vertically

Comment: please provide JS errors

Comment: Thank you for quick replay martins . js error is  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetLeft' of undefined"

Comment: are You using apache with some modules ? might be problems with .htaccess

Comment: Yes i am using apache

Comment: i stop ModPagespeed off in  .htaccess file problem is solved

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :)